# Encounter Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2) when using custom segue

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, uistoryboardsegue, presentviewcontroller

I stuck on this bug for almost a month now. I created a custom segue called SegueFromRight. I pretty much copy the code from some online tutorials. The segue worked for my loginView, but it always crashed at a later scene. The view was already presented and the animation was also executed. It crashed after a few seconds after the segue was performed and gave me the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed362ff8)
```

I have checked my View and I didn't find any dangling outlet. And it is very strange that this error did not happen if I used standard segue like Show or Show Detail. It only happened when I try to use this custom segue. The error happened at the line:

```
src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The complete code is pasted below. The code called by this line are written in assembly (I guess?). So I had a hard time debugging. I did look into it. The bug happened lowest at libMainThreadChecker.dylib`checker_c, which is called in presentViewController. The line which gives the error is:

```
0x1064f8d98 <+26>:  callq  0x1064fa3da               ; symbol stub for: pthread_main_np
```

Can anyone identify my problem? Thank you so much! And if you need any more code, feel free to leave a comment.

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        moveInFromRight()
    }

    func moveInFromRight() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)
        src.view.superview?.addSubview(dst.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil) // gives the error
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is illegal. You cannot perform a transform on the destination view or add the destination view directly to the source view like that. If your goal is to do a presentation with a custom animation, you must write a properly constructed custom transition animation for your presentation. The fact that you are using a custom segue can help you encapsulate the custom transition animation code, but it doesn't change the rules for how you must do this. You must set the destination view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`, set its `transitioningDelegate`, and supply a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate or a UIPresentationController subclass or both, just as with any custom presentation animation.

Comment: Could you please give an example or point me to the place where I can learn how to do this? Because all the online tutorials I saw are implemented in this way. So I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Another question is that do you mean that all these online tutorials are not doing it correctly? For example, the one in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn-93qElOT4. My class is almost the same as his, except the animation part.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p325customSegue/CustomSegue/ViewController.swift is a very basic example, and yes I probably do mean that but I’m not interested in looking at a tutorial video, I’m interested in teaching you the right way